# How to get X number of evenly distributed rows in a mysql daterange?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm working with a large Mysql table (300M records), the primary key is a datetime value.
How can I efficiently get a specific number of rows that are evenly distributed in a specified datetime range?

For example: For 1000 rows in a datetimerange and 200 numbers rows needed, I would like to end up with every 5th row.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, you might even be able to get away with doing it without a subquery, but this safer and more reliable.

```
SET @i := -1;

SELECT *, @i := @i + 1 AS rowNum
(
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE theField BETWEEN [begin] AND [end]
ORDER BY theField
) AS subQ
HAVING rowNum % 5 == 0
;
```

This doesn't really guarantee 200 out of 1000 though, you could have a number of rows in the range not divisible by 5.